# Bluetooth HC-05 not pairing to another HC-05 module

Tags: bluetooth, at-command, hc-05

I have two HC-05 modules and want to communicate between them (one in master mode, the other as slave).
I have the Module types with EN pin ans a little button on the PCB.
Both Modules, I resetted with the ORGL command, so they both have default setting.

First Module: I just power on with no connection of EN pin.
Module starts and the LED is blinking fast.

Second Module: I set EN pin to High and power on the Module.
Module starts and the LED is 2seconds on/2seconds off, so Im in the command mode.

Now I send following commands to the Module:

```
AT
 OK
AT+VERSION
 +VERSION:4.0-20190815
 OK
AT+ORGL
 OK
AT+ROLE=1
 OK
AT+RESET
 OK
AT+INIT
 ERROR: [0]
AT+RMAAD
 OK
AT+INQ
 +INQ:0021:04:062C93,1F00,FFD0,HC-05
 OK
AT+STATE?
 +STATE:INITIALIZED
 OK
AT+PAIR=0021,04,062C93
---> No answer
```

First I'm wondering: The module is always in state "initialized". I have never seen any other stade. I suggest something like "READY" or "PAIRABLE", but get never this states.
Is there any delailed description what the states exaclty mean? I didn't found details about them.

Second I'm wondering: The init command sends ERROR0, so it seems that the module didn't know this command? On all tutorials in the internet, this command is used, I have never read about that this command may not exists on some modules?

Third I'm wondering: AT+RAIR returns no answer.
I also tryed to send the pin 1234 after entering this command (I read this in another thread), but still nothing hapens.
--> Maybe this is not working, because the state is INITIALIZED instead of ready or pairable?

On [another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010342/bluetooth-hc-05-sending-error-1f-for-inq-command-only) I read that there are two command modes for HC-05, one with a reduced command set, but this not seems to be the problem, because in the reduced command set normally INQ is not working, but this command is working here.
So, i suggest, it has something to do with the state of the module. Why its always INITIALIZED? Never READY or PAIRABLE?
I have tryed the procedure with both modules. Both have the same behavoir.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: `On all tutorials in the internet...` While such tutorials might be useful, what you really, really, really, really, really need is the **official**, **authoritative** AT command documentation for the HC-05 product. That will most likely answer a significant part of your questions, as well as helping you achieve correct and accurate result.

Comment: Whomever nominated this question for closure as "not about programming or software development" is utterly wrong. There is no scope mismatch with this question for this site.