# How do I get the signal quality of the connected Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

Merhaba,

How do I get the signal quality of the connected Bluetooth device.

I connect to the HC05 module(Arduino Module), I will do a job when I get close to the module about 1 meter, the signal strength will give an idea.

Comment: There are many results if you search for "hc05 signal strengh". This is one of them: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98160/how-to-get-rssi-of-bluetooth-specfically-hc-05 Keep in mind that the RSSI value is not very reliable and will change fast even without movement depending on your environment

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/hc-05-signal-strength/859989/7?u=yhackup

please read  my reply

Comment: Have you tried AC+INQ and it did not work? This explains a solution if the command fails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221336/hc-05-bluetooth-rssi-not-working-with-arduino You might have to press the button r connect pin 34 to be able to use AT commands

Comment: @M.Kotzjan The android application communicates with the hc 05, while the android is connected to the arduino, it will ask the quality of the connection and the arduino will reply.
If the match is broken, how will my android application learn the quality?

Comment: I'm just suggesting you try setting pin 34 on your hc 05 to high as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31123033/7473793 and try AC+INQ again. Setting the pin to high (or pressing the button on the board) allows you to enter the AT command mode